# Add parent node to XML node with R XML Package

Tags: r, xml

I am new to R XML package. Need some help to add parent node to child node. 
I have a XMLNode as below. and need to enclose child node called `<Point>` within `<outerBoundaryIs>`

```
  <Placemark>
    <name>13</name>
    <styleUrl>#pnt1</styleUrl>
    <description><![CDATA[Weak-11]]></description>
    <Point>
      <extrude>1</extrude>
      <altitudeMode>relativeToGround</altitudeMode>
      <coordinates>45.8851,17.2057,0</coordinates>
    </Point>
  </Placemark>
```

So that i get below in output

```
    <outerBoundaryIs>
        <Point>
...
        </Point>
    </outerBoundaryIs>
```